# How to filter out file names from a .File.Glob in a Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, glob, go-templates

I have the following snippet in a helm library which is supposed to add in all the files in a folder into a ConfigMap except for those ending in .tz.

```
{{- /*
  add the contents of every file in the config folder of this IOC helm chart
  into the config map - this must include start.sh the startup script.
  The files must be text only. Any files ending in .tz are explicitly ommitted
*/ -}}

{{ (.Files.Glob "config/*[!.tz]").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
  version.txt: |
    IOC {{ .Release.Name }} version {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
```

This does not quite work in that it filters out all files ending in . or t or z.

I cant see how to do this with Go globbing. I also cannot work out the syntax for using 'without' for the list created by `.Files.Glob`.

Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @David Maze. This almost worked but the reference to .Files.Get failed and I think that is because the . context becomes the range counter within the range loop.

Adding $ to .Files within the loop got it working.

Also to fully replicate AsConfig I needed to extract the basename from
the path which I did by adding regexReplaceAll.

```
data:
{{- range $path, $_ := .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
{{- if not (hasSuffix ".tz" $path) }}
  {{ regexReplaceAll "(.*)/" $path "" }}: |
{{ $.Files.Get $path | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Helm documentation references the Go [`"github.com/gobwas/glob"`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gobwas/glob) package for the supported glob syntax; that doesn't support any sort of "except" cases, except for single characters.

What you can do instead is iterate over all of the files, and then use a normal conditional to exclude the ones you don't want.  You have to construct the ConfigMap structure yourself rather than relying on the `AsConfig` helper.

```yaml
data:
{{- range $path, $_ := .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
{{- if not (hasSuffix ".tz" $path) }}
  {{ $path }}: |
{{ .Files.Get $path | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```